# Laravel 5.5 - Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk, db:seed not running

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.5 app that I am trying to deploy to an Amazon Elastic Beanstalk instance.

The upload process goes find and I can access the site, I need to init the database so I log into the instance as ec2-user and run the following commands..

```
php artisan migrate
php artisan db:seed
```

The first command correctly executes and the database is populated with the correct tables, but the second command does not work and gives me the error...

```
The stream or file "/var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Anyone any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set permission

```
sudo chmod  -R 755 /var/app/current/storage

sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/app/current/storage/logs/*
```

Comment: Not having any effect

Comment: Thanks, that got it